# Exceeding memory limit or time limit

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm attempting to create a program that will multiply 3 not equal positions from vector 1 ('V1'), and find the maximum multiplication.

I'm using 3 'for' loops for counting and writing. The program gets the position amount 'N', then all 'N' numbers in 'input.txt'. After that, it gets the greatest position 'max' and writes it in 'output.exe'.

But I need to keep the program as efficient as possible, 16 MB memory limit and 1 second time limit (I get 1.004 second and 33 MB). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    long long max = -9223372036854775807;
    int input;

    vector<long long> V1;

    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("input.txt");
    file1 >> N;

    V1.resize(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        file1 >> V1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                if (V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k] > max)
                {
                    max = V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k];
                }

    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("output.txt");
    file2 << max;
    file2.close();
}
```

#### File *Input.txt*

```
 5
    10 10 10 -300 - 300
```

Comment: Avoid the calculation and `pop_back` by doing the`if` first could give a little. Hmm... Do you need the `if`at all?

Comment: Maybe `V1.resize` before the `push_back` would help. You would only have one memory allocation if you did that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the `If` was a leftover from previous version on the program, I deleted it now. Now I'm using 1 integer instead a whole vector to store maximum number.

Comment: Then you should update your description. The description kind of states that the program must store the results in a vector. But now you have kind of changed the requirements to only be: find the maximum. That is two very different programs. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at what you have done, you have to find the greatest of the product of 3 numbers in a given input vector.

Just sort vector V1 and output the max of (product of 1st 3 elements or 1st and last 2 elements). This is efficient in both space and time.

Like this:

```
sort(V1.begin(),V1.end(),greater<int>())   //sorts in descending order
int n = V1.size()-1;
output max(V1[0] * V1[1] * V1[2], V1[0] * V1[n] * V1[n-1])
```

Comment: Imagine the following input: `1 2 3 -10000 -10000`. Your program outputs `6`, while the correct answer is `300,000,000`

Comment: Oh...I missed that case...I'll edit my answer for that. Thanks for the case...Also, I don't think there is any other case that will violate this.

Comment: Nice one :) I can't imagine a breaking case, too. Just for clarification - this algorithm takes **`O(N * log(N))`** time.

Comment: Yes, It takes n * log(n) time.

Answer (score 2):

The first, which comes to my mind - why do you store these values? You only need the single maximum value - there is no need to store all these values, push them, and, moreover, sort them out.

Another important notices:

- You have a vector of `long long`, but you read `int`s. Since you have big numbers in your input, use `long long` everywhere
- Pushing an item and popping it back is senseless - you should have checked it before pushing to avoid two unnecessary operations
- Anyway, you don't need to compare `i`, `j`, `k` for equivalence at all - they are never equal according to your loop restrictions
- Pushing items to an array when you know their number is wrong. It takes more time to extend a vector. You may want to resize it to the given size.

Probably, this code will meet your memory \ time requirements:

```
int N; 
long long maximum = -9223372036854775807; // Subject to limits.h LLONG_MIN usage
vector<long long> V1;

ifstream file1;
file1.open("input.txt");
file1 >> N;

V1.resize(N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    file1 >> V1[i];
}

file1.close();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            if (V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k] > maximum)
                maximum = V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k];                

ofstream file2;
file2.open("output.txt");
file2 << maximum;
file2.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help !. but now I have another problem, when I input 3 30000 30000 3000 the program displays wrong answer

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan Ok, my bad. I have used `int` everywhere instead of `long long`. Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: You need to change `V1.reserve(N);` to `V1.resize(N);`. When you only do reserve the vector is still "empty" and accessing those elements is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks for clarification :) I have updated the answer.

Comment: I updated the program, but it still exeeds the time, giving 1.36 when I input 3 30000 30000 3000

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan It shouldn't :( It is only numbers, which will be calculated in a moment. Check this demo: http://ideone.com/mlqr52. It took 0.00s to complete. It is the same code, but without file input \ output.

Comment: Actually it should exceed time. Your code is O(n^3)...which is not acceptable.

Comment: @ YeldarKurmangaliyev Hm.. that's interesting. I should use another compiller then. Thank you for your kind help ! :)

Comment: @vish4071 Of course, it may be improved by some hacky conditions like searching the biggest three numbers, or two biggest negative and one biggest positive, but it definitely shouldn't exceed the time when you enter 3 numbers :)

Comment: Obvs for 3 input numbers, anything is ok. But even for a small input like 1000 numbers, your code will exceed 1s.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as soon as I see size and time reduction, I tend to remove all unnecessary language goodies, because they do help in proper programming but only come at a resource expense.

So if you really wanted to keep all products of different indices of a list of values, I would advice you to throw away vectors, push and pop and use fixed size arrays.

But before that low-level optimisation, we **must** think of all possible algorithmic optimisations. You only want be biggest products from all possible from three different values taken from a list. But for positive numbers, a >= b <=> a *c >= b *c and the product of two negative numbers is positive.

So the highest product may only come from:

- product of three highest positive values
- product of one highest positive value and two lowest negative values (highest in absolute value)
- product of three highest negative values if there are no positive values

So you do not even need to load the full initial vector but just keep:

- Three highest positive values
- Three highest negative values
- Two lowest negative values

You get them by storing them at read time in O(n) time and only store eight values. If you only have five values, it is not efficient at all, but it will be linear in time and constant in size whatever number of values you process.

Possible implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

class Max3 {
    long long pmax[3];
    long long nmax[3];
    long long nmin[2];

    void push(long long *record, long long val, size_t pos) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<pos; i++) {
            record[i] = record[i + 1];
        }
        record[pos] = val;
    }

    void set(long long *record, long long val, size_t sz) {
        for (size_t i=1; i<sz; i++) {
            if (val < record[i]) {
                push(record, val, i - 1);
                return;
            }
        }
        push(record, val, sz - 1);
    }

public:
    Max3() {
        size_t i;
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(pmax)/sizeof(pmax[0]); i++)
            pmax[i] = 0;
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(nmin)/sizeof(nmin[0]); i++)
            nmin[i] = 0;
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(nmax)/sizeof(nmax[0]); i++)
            nmax[i] = LLONG_MIN;
    }

    void test(long long val) {
        if (val >= *pmax) {
            set(pmax, val, 3);
        }
        else if (val <= 0) {
            if (val <= *nmin) {
                set(nmin, -val, 2);
            }
            if (val >= *nmax) {
                set(nmax, val, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    long long getMax() {
        long long max = 0, prod, pm;
        if ((prod = pmax[0] * pmax[1] * pmax[2]) > max)
            max = prod;

        if (pmax[2] > 0)
            pm = pmax[2];
        else if (pmax[1] > 0)
            pm = pmax[1];
        else
            pm = pmax[0];

        if ((prod = nmin[0] * nmin[1] * pm) > max)
            max = prod;

        if ((prod = nmax[0] * nmax[1] * nmax[2]) > max)
            max = prod;
        return max;
    }
};


int main() {
    int N;
    long long input;
    Max3 m3;

    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("input.txt");
    file1 >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        file1 >> input;
        m3.test(input);
    }
    file1.close();

    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("output.txt");
    file2 << m3.getMax();
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is slightly more complex, but the program size is only 35 KB, with little dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the 'for' loops with a sort of vector 1 'V1' (in descending order), the program compares the products 'V1[0] * V1[1] * V1[2]' and 'V1[0] * V1[N] * V1[N - 1', and then prints the maximum in file *output.txt*:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    long long max = -9223372036854775807;
    int input;

    vector<long long> V1;

    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("input.txt");
    file1 >> N;

    V1.resize(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        file1 >> V1[i];
    }

    sort(V1.begin(), V1.end(), greater<int>());

    N -= 1;

    max = V1[0] * V1[1] * V1[2];

    if (max < V1[0] * V1[N] * V1[N - 1])
        max = V1[0] * V1[N] * V1[N - 1];

    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("output.txt");
    file2 << max;
    file2.close();
}
```